# install4j MSI Installer - Random name when asking for permissions

Tags: install4j

When I create an MSI installer with install4j, when the installer asks for permissions (the UAC prompt), the program name for the installer is a randome set of letters and numbers (i.e. 2e5658ae.msi).

The program name should really show our application name.

Is there a way to set this value in the install4j installer settings?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this Problem?